# Print Calendar in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to print a calendar without using any date functions like datediff, dateadd, datename etc.

Below is my code I have not used any date functions, I am stuck with the dayname now.
For the month and year entered I should get a day as sunday, monday etc.

So I got a hint like I take any date of my wish as reference ex: 2/13/2014 ,

7 days before it was feb 6th that is thursday. Again 7 days before feb 6th is Jan 30th and it is also thursday ,In same way after feb 13th its  feb 20th will be  thursday. Based on this logic can we get? without using date functions.

Plz help

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].Calendar1 
   (
    @month int,
    @Year  int
   )
AS  
BEGIN
   DECLARE @startdateofMonthYear DATE, @EnddateofMonthYear DATE

   SET @startdateofMonthYear = (SELECT CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '' + Right('00' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '-' + '01')

   SET @EnddateofMonthYear = (SELECT case when @month IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) then cast(@Year as varchar(4)) +'-'+Right('00'+Cast(@month as varchar(2)),2) +'-'+'31'when @month IN(4,6,9,11) then cast(@Year as varchar(4)) +'-'+Right('00'+Cast(@month as varchar(2)),2) +'-'+'30'    
  else  cast(@Year as varchar(4)) +'-'+Right('00'+Cast(@month as varchar(2)),2) +'-'+(CASE WHEN (@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0 THEN '29' else '28' End) 
   End) 

 ;WITH CTE_DatesTable
  AS
(
Select 1 daysint, Cast(SUBSTRING(cast(@startdateofMonthYear as varchar(20)),1,7) + '-'+CAST(1 as varchar(2)) as DATE) Calendardates

UNION ALL
SELECT   daysint+1,Cast(SUBSTRING(cast(@startdateofMonthYear as varchar(20)),1,7) + '-'+CAST(daysint+1 as varchar(2)) as DATE) Calendardates
FROM CTE_DatesTable
WHERE  daysint<=
(SELECT case when @month IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) then 31
                        when @month IN(4,6,9,11) then 30    
                        else  (CASE WHEN (@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0 THEN 29 else 28 End) 
                        End)-1
 )
 Select 
 [DWDateKey]=Calendardates,
 [DayDate]=daysint,
 [MonthNumber]=@Month,
 [MonthName]=Case            when @month  = 1 then 'January'
             when @month  = 2 then 'February'
             when @month  = 3 then 'March'
             when @month  = 4 then 'April'
             when @month  = 5 then 'May'
             when @month  = 6 then 'June'
             when @month  = 7 then 'July'
             when @month  = 8 then 'August'
             when @month  = 9 then 'September'
             when @month  = 10 then 'October'
             when @month  = 11 then 'November'
             when @month  = 12 then 'December' 
        End,
   [Year]=@Year--,datename(dw,Calendardates) weekname

   From CTE_DatesTable
    END
```

Comment: Print in SQL? Are you talking about `SELECT`, `PRINT` or printing to a printing device, I'm confused...I'm also confused about why you cant use any of the mentioned datetime functions that obviously have built-in functionalities to remove all the "business logic" you are implementing to this poor stored procedure

Comment: Its an assignment , without using any date functions it should display a calendar. this procedure does that .